# Does Django Optimize the query if it gets run multiple times with the same filter?

Tags: django, django-models

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    task_id = models.UUIDField()
    task_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+')
    task = GenericForeignKey('task_type', 'task_id')
    .....


    @property
    def task_description(self):
        if self.task_status === 'pending':
            return 'Pending Task'
        else:
            task = Task.objects.filter(self.task_id).first()
            return task.name or ''
```

In case `self.task_status` is not `pending`, then for each task, it looks up the Task table for the name.

My Question.

1. suppose task ids `[1,2,3,3,3]` then what will be the queries that get run ?
2. is this N+1 problem ?
3. for id `1`, it checks the Task table where id = 1. for 2 3 it does too. But for `id == 3`, does it look up the table 3 times with same filter like `where id = 3` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since you're using generic foreign keys, multiple queries may run per lookup. I would recommend using [`django-polymorphic`](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) instead if you need true model inheritance (different models for different task types with a common base class).
2. Yes, accessing `task_description` for N MyModels that aren't `pending` will do N extra queries.
3. Yes, it does. Those lookups happen in isolation, so for 5 MyModels, you get 5 queries.